# How to get my server to tell a client to close connection?

Tags: python, sockets, server, connection, client

I am writing a simple chat room program using python. Lets say the user enters the command to exit the chat room. On the server side, I can simply close the connection by doing connection.close(), but what if I want the server to tell the client to close the connection also? I was thinking I could write a function on the client side and import it, but that doesn't work because upon importing the function, it tries to run the whole client.py file before the server is up. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: If you have a reliable network and the server closes the connection, the client will notice and raise an exception that should be handled.

Comment: You can't. All you can do is close your socket and hope that the client is correctly coded to recognize end of stream and close his. If he doesn't. it's his problem, not yours: his ports will accumulate in CLOSE_WAIT state until he runs out: but it doesn't consume any resources at your side.

Comment: @Community Yet another incorrect robomessage. The question does not require code to be answered. It is ultimately about the TCP protocol, not specific code.